# Do the functions have zero on the interval $[-n_{f},+n_{f}]$ } a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, contest-math

> Denote by $E$ the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of all mappings from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Rigorously justifying your answer in each case, indicate whether the following subsets of $E$ are vector subspaces of $E$.
>
> $$H=\{f \in E \text{ such that : there is a nonzero integer $n_{f}$ such that $f$ is zero on the interval $[-n_{f},+n_{f}]$ } \}$$.

H is Vector subspace of E if and only if :

- $H\neq \emptyset$
- if $f,g \in H$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then $(af+bg )\in H $

Indeed

H can be expressed by :
$$H=\{f\in E / \ \exists\  n_{f} \in \mathbb{N_*} : f=0 \text{ on } [-n_{f},+n_{f}] \} $$

let $f,g \in H$ then
$$ f =\begin{cases}0 & [-n_{f},+n_{f}]\\1 & \mathbb{N}  \setminus  [-n_{f},+n_{f}] \end{cases} $$

$$ g =\begin{cases}0 & [-m_{f},+m_{f}]\\1 & \mathbb{N} \setminus  [-m_{f},+m_{f}] \end{cases} $$

such that $n_{f} \neq m_{g}$ and  $[-n_{f},+n_{f}] \cap [-m_{g},+m_{g}]= \emptyset$

I think $H$ isn't subspace of E that's why i'm trying to come up with conterexample

would you help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one. $0\mapsto 0\in H$; and for $f,g\in H$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, $\lambda f$ is zero on $[-n_f, n_f]$ and $f+g$ is zero on $[-\min(n_f,n_g), \min(n_f,n_g)]$, hence $\lambda f\in H$ and $f+g\in H$.

You cannot find any two non-zero integers $n,m$ such that $[-n,n]\cap [-m,m]=\emptyset$: $[-n,n]\cap [-m,m]=[-\min(n,m),\min(n,m)]$ and $\min(n,m)$ is a non-zero integer..

Comment: just one question if we have to do $\cap$  we have to $[-\max(n_f,n_g), \max(n_f,n_g)]$

Comment: No: the intersection is the smallest interval. If for instance $n=1$, and $m=2$, $[-1,1]\cap [-2,2] = [-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

It was a good idea looking for a counterexample, but your execution is a bit off. Indeed, it's not possible to find two nonzero integers such that $[-n,n] \cap [-m,m] = \emptyset$: $0$ is always in the intersection! In fact, if $n < m$, then $[-n,n]$ is contained in the intersection. This should tip you off in the right direction (and help you check the second axiom of a vector subspace, the first one is easy): $H$ is actually a vector subspace of $E$. Indeed, if $f,g \in H$, say $f$ vanishes on $[-n,n]$ and $g$ vanishes on $[-m,m]$, let $k = \min(n,m)$, then $\lambda f + \eta g$ vanishes on $[-k,-k]$ and so belongs to $H$.